# how to to check if jQuery is loaded from C# code?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm developing a WEB_PART and I'd like to know if there some way to find out if exists any JQUERY LIB inside the master page project where the web part is going to be inserted.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
  if (jQuery) {  
 // jQuery is loaded  
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebpartSlideShow), "jQuery",                        "/_layouts/Jquery-Cycle/jquery-1.5.1.min.js");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebpartSlideShow), "jQueryCycle", "/_layouts/Jquery-Cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js");
               // break;
   } else {
  // jQuery is not loaded
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebpartSlideShow), "jQueryCycle", "/_layouts/Jquery-Cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js");

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/255xet9e.aspx

```
Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("jQuery");
```

You should probably define some constants though.

Comment: It is important to note that this will **only** work if jQuery was added through `Page.ClientScript`. If jQuery was added in plain HTML, this method will not work and will cause the page to load two instances of jQuery.

Comment: and how can I do this if I add jQuery in plain HTML?

Comment: You can't, well u can if you start fishing for it in the response, you don't want to go there. The ClientScriptManager is designed for tracking client scripts.